# Firebase Database wont be connected to App in TestFlight

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect

Hey there so I just uploaded my first app to App Store Connect. The verification is still pending, but I as the admin got to test the App before that. My Problem is that my Database Firebase won't work with the App version I got from test flight will this be changed when the App is verified?

Comment: Is your firebase database the Realtime database, or the Cloud Firestore database?

Comment: No! There is doc for both `Swift` and `Objective-C`. You just need to toggle the language tab showing on top of each code snippet. Have a look at this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?authuser=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will encourage you to look through the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). It has code samples in swift as well as Objective C.
As far as your requirement is concerned, if you are using Realtime Database, you'll do it this way:

```
[[[_ref child:@"user"] childByAutoId] setValue:@"1"];
```